# An enclosing polygon with minimum area

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, algorithms, computational-geometry, dynamic-programming

For a given set of $n$ points (in $ℝ^2$) find an enclosing polygon with minimum area. It seems that at first we need to triangulate the given set, and find an areas of all triangles. But I can't figure out what I have to do next. Maybe some kind of dynamic programming like $dp_{i,j}$ - an answer for first $i$ points where $j$th triangle is included to the polygon.

[image: An example]

Comment: It would also be pertinent to ask whether any triangulation can give a minimal area polygon. Or do you have to take care also when triangulating? I think it's the latter, but I don't know. Also, it seems that you implicitly require that the polygon has no vertices other than the given points, and is non-degenerate. Is that correct?

Comment: @Arthur , the polygon I want to find has no other vertices because otherwise we always can add new point and make the area smaller. triangulation is the first idea that came to my mind when I tried to come up with an algorithm

Comment: What exactly is an "enclosing polygon" here?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter, a polygon such that all points of the set belong to the interior or to the boundary of the polygon

Comment: Do you allow holes in your enclosing polygon? Actually should the enclosing polygon be simple?

Comment: @N.Bach, yes, is should be simple